Issue with Pasting Rows in Tabulator - Limiting to Copied Rows
I'm experiencing an issue with the pasting functionality in Tabulator and need assistance in restricting the number of rows pasted to match the number of rows copied. I'm using Tabulator 6.2.
When I copy 3 rows from another source (like Excel or Google Sheets) and paste them into the Tabulator table, I expect only those 3 rows to be pasted. However, if I copy more than 3 rows, it pastes the selection multiple times.
I have attempted to use both clipboardPaste and clipboardPasted events to limit the pasted rows, but it seems that the duplication issue persists.
I've ensured that the pasted data is correctly parsed, but the limiting logic does not seem to affect the actual insertion into the table.
Thanks for the help.
